# Browserify and ES6/ES2015 classes (babel compiler)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs, commonjs

I have 2 classes (ES2015 Classes style) in separate files and one App file with require. I want to use this CommonJS modules in browser. Most popular lib is Browserify with Babel compiler for ES2015 syntax (babelify).
Example:

Class1.js

```
class Class1 {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = 1;
  }
  method() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
}
module.exports = Class1;
```

Class2.js

```
class Class2 {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = 2;
  }
  method() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
}
module.exports = Class2;
```

App.js

```
var Class1 = require('./Class1');
var Class2 = require('./Class2');
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.class1 = new Class1();
    this.class2 = new Class2();
  }
}
module.exports = App;
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task("js", function () {
  browserify({ entries: config.js.appFile, extensions: ['.js'], debug: true })
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(config.js.appMinFile))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

The **problem** in result app.js. It contains duplicate code for each classes in each modules.

```
var _createClass = function () { ... }
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { ...}
function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { ... } //not for example above but can exists
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { ... } //not for example above but can exists
```

How to remove this duplicate code **with sourcemap support** for source js files?

I tried Browserify all js files in one without Babelify transform, then compile result with Babel. It works without duplicate code but sourcemap will incorrect.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I want to use CommonJS module system with ES2015 syntax with simple debuging in browser.

Comment: Try bundling before transpiling.

Comment: Are you using any new ES6 prototype methods? The easiest way to do this is to use `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`/`babel-runtime` instead of `babel-polyfill`.

Comment: Whats do you mean "any new ES6 prototype methods"? Can you write an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you should `npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-runtime` and then include

```
"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
```

in your `.babelrc` alongside your `"presets": ["es2015"]` configuration.

The exact answer depends on how you want your polyfill functions to work. Babel provides `babel-polyfill` as a way to globally load a polyfill that will add ES6 library functions throughout your application. However this can conflict with the default behavior of `transform-runtime` above, which will instead attempt to point references to globals back at the `babel-runtime` module. This means you could accidentally end up with two copies of the same polyfilled APIs loaded.

1. If you want/need to use `babel-polyfill` because it globally provides tons of standard ES6 functionality, including global prototype methods like `Array.prototype.includes`, then you should add additional params to your plugin:

   ```
   "plugins": [
     ["transform-runtime", {polyfill: false, regenerator: false}],
   ]
   ```
2. If you don't want to use a globally-polluting polyfill like `babel-polyfill`, you can use the polyfilling logic in `babel-runtime` instead. This can be important if for instance you are writing a standalone library and don't want to make all your users load `babel-polyfill` for you, or change globals from the library, which is a bad idea.

   ```
   "plugins": [
     "transform-runtime",
   ]
   ```